# how to use Multiple POST angujarjs node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I would like use UPDATE post but I didn't receive the request with the, well app.post

The request is sent with $scope.UPDATE but I receive a response from add.post(OMG), not from michel !

In console I receive response from omg, not michel. why and how to solve this

**controller:**

```js
$scope.add = function (contact) {
  var omg = JSON.stringify(contact);
  console.log(omg);
  $http.post('/contactlist/' + omg).then(function (response) {
    refresh();
  });
};

$scope.update = function (contact) {
  var michel = JSON.stringify(contact);
  $http.post('/contactlist/' + michel).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    refresh();
  });
};
```

**server side:**

```
app.post('/contactlist/:omg', function (req, res) {
  var omg = req.params.omg;
  var test = JSON.parse(omg);
  console.log(omg);
  // var name = JSON.parse(omg, 1);
  var array = [ [test.name, test.email, test.number] ];
  connection.query('INSERT INTO contactlist (name, email, number) VALUES ?', [array], function (error, results, fields) {
    res.json();
  });
});

app.post('/contactlist/:michel', function (req, res) {
    console.log("testtestetstest");
    res.json();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/contactlist/omg', function (req, res) {
    var omg = req.params.omg;
    var test = JSON.parse(omg);
    console.log(omg);
    // var name = JSON.parse(omg, 1);
    var array = [ [test.name, test.email, test.number] ];
    connection.query('INSERT INTO contactlist (name, email, number) VALUES ?', [array], function (error, results, fields) {
        res.json();
    });
});

app.post('/contactlist/michel', function (req, res) {
    console.log("testtestetstest");
    res.json();
});
```

Remove `:param` from your server side and use `/param` if you want to hardcode an endpoint. `:` is used in front of a placeholder variable to mean that the endpoint will change depending on the scenario. E.g: `/users/:user` means `/users/mark` and `/users/john` are all legit endpoints. But `/users/user`, means `/users/mark` will be a 404.